# how to select particular row data in SQLite db and pass it to other activity in Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity

I'm using SQLite db and Android Studio.I have DatabaseHelper class and I want to pass a particular table's row data to other activity. I'm currently using select with where clause for doing this.
Code for DatabaseHelper class is as follows:

```
public int senderMobile(String activeuser){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select mobile from user where email=?",new String[]{activeuser});
            int mobile = cursor.getColumnIndex("mobile");
            return mobile;
    }
```

I am calling this senderMobile method from my activity where I want the table's row data. The code of activity.java file is as follow:

```
int senderMobile=db.senderMobile(activeuser);
```

From the above code my db I'm always getting 0 in the activity.java, my expectation is that **9999999999** is returned.

Please someone help me to get the correct data from the table. thankyou

Comment: I am not passing values from one activity to another. I want to get the data from the db table and pass it to other activity. I'm stuck because I get 0 as the value.

Comment: I guess "pass it to other activity" in the title could be misleading

Comment: Maybe, But it also has "select particular row data". anyways thankyou @A.Edwar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three issues.

- First you are getting the **column index** of the column **not data from the column itself**.
- Second you are **not moving** to a valid row from which to retrieve the data.
- Third, according to your comments you are extracting a **java integer (int)** when according to your comments the number is too large for an integer (hence why you get 1410065407), so you need to use a **long**.

The following code should work:-

```
    public long senderMobile(String activeuser){ //<<<< NOTE long
        long rv = -1; //<<<< default return to indicate no such row
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select mobile from user where email=?",new String[]{activeuser});
        if (cursor.moveToFirst) { //<<<< Move to the first row (should only be 1)
            rv = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("mobile"); //<< get the data from the column
        }
        return rv;
    }
```

- You should check the value returned from the senderMobile, -1 indicates that no such row was found and code accordingly.
- Note the above code is in-principle, it has not been tested so may contain errors.

Comment: Now the code is working properly after changing the int to float. I'm getting the correct senderMobile data. Thanks mate

Comment: Similarly if I want to select string from the table and pass it to other screen, what changes should be made to the above code??

Comment: Where it has **`long`** change to **`String`* including changing  **`getLong`** to **`getString`**.

Comment: @PranitDarekar if this answers your question then please tick the question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the column index of the "mobile" column as a the value, so it will always return zero

So it should be

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    return cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("mobile"))
}
return 0;
```

Comment: by doing this I'm getting following error:android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1 @A.Edwar

Comment: final code for senderMobile:  </br> public int senderMobile(String activeuser){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select mobile from user where email=?",new String[]{activeuser});
        if (cursor.moveToLast()) {
            return cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("mobile"));
        }

    }

Comment: just add return 0 in the end incase the if block didn't execute, I edited my answer.

Comment: Now I think it is returning a garbage value because the data in table is 9999999999 but the method is returning 1410065407

Comment: if you have more than one record in the database then there could be an issue with your query, I noticed that you passed the ActiveUser as an Email, I don't know it could be it.

Comment: There are many records in the table but for a given activeuser there is only one record in the table. yes i have passed activeuser as an email because activeuser has the email of the currently logged in user.

Comment: So activeuser is the email or the id of the user or the name of the user?

Comment: activeuser is the email of the user which is passed from the login screen where user logins using email. this email is stored in activeuser and passed to other screens.

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("mobile"))
```

You are just fetching index of the mobile field not fetching the actual value from the cursor. Above one line will fetch the value also

Comment: the above code is giving me an error :android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Comment: @PranitDarekar use this cursor.moveToFirst() before fetching the value

Comment: Now I think it is returning a garbage value because the data in table is 9999999999 but the method is returning 1410065407

Comment: @PranitDarekar What is the data type you have added to mobile column in the db

Comment: mobile column is integer